# Why sortWith(lt: (A, A) => Boolean) require a function with two params but can use compareTo which have only one param?

Tags: scala, scala-placeholder-syntax

As https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#sortWith(lt:(A,A)=%3EBoolean) :

```
List("Steve", "Tom", "John", "Bob").sortWith(_.compareTo(_) < 0) = List("Bob", "John", "Steve", "Tom")
```

the param of sortWith is:

```
lt: (A, A) => Boolean
```

where a function with two params and return a boolean

but compareTo have only one param:

```
def compareTo(that: A): Int
```

if compareTo is a function,it have two params.but it's scala,so compareTo is a method,it's have only one param

so why there can use compareTo in sortWith?It seems not accord with the type signature of sortWith

Comment: Notice the function passed to `sortWith` is not `compareTo`, but the lambda `_.compareTo(_) < 0`.

Comment: On what are you calling `compareTo`? On a magic object created out of no where? No, you are calling it in the object passed as the first argument of the function. If we remove the sugar syntax of the `_` syntax it should be clear: `_.compareTo(_)` is equivalent to `(a1, a2) => a1.compareTo(a2)` so you can clearly see you have a two arguments function :)

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I believe your comment should be posted as an answer ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This usage of underscore is known as [Placeholder Syntax for Anonymous Functions](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/06-expressions.html#placeholder-syntax-for-anonymous-functions):

> Such an expression represents an anonymous function where subsequent
> occurrences of underscores denote **successive** parameters.

Note each underscore refers to different parameter so for example

```
_ + _
```

expands to

```
(x1, x2) => x1 + x2
```

Also expression `_ + _` makes use of point-free syntax as opposed to

```
_.+(_)
```

for example

```
List("Steve", "Tom", "John", "Bob").reduce((x1: String, x2: String) => x1.+(x2)) // : String = "SteveTomJohnBob"
List("Steve", "Tom", "John", "Bob").reduce((x1, x2) => x1.+(x2)) // : String = "SteveTomJohnBob"
List("Steve", "Tom", "John", "Bob").reduce(_.+(_)) // : String = "SteveTomJohnBob"
List("Steve", "Tom", "John", "Bob").reduce(_ + _) // : String = "SteveTomJohnBob"
```

so now it should be clearer why expression `_.compareTo(_) < 0` works

```
List("Steve", "Tom", "John", "Bob").sortWith(_.compareTo(_) < 0) // : List[String] = List("Bob", "John", "Steve", "Tom")
List("Steve", "Tom", "John", "Bob").sortWith((x1, x2) => x1.compareTo(x2) < 0) // : List[String] = List("Bob", "John", "Steve", "Tom")
```

Another way to see this let's type-ascribe the sugared expression

```
scala> (_.compareTo(_) < 0): ((String, String) => Boolean)
val res0: (String, String) => Boolean = $Lambda$7865/418832725@18987bf5
```